# Cancelling file download with httpclient and asynctask

Tags: android, httpclient, android-asynctask

In my app I need to download files from url locations. I want to display progress of the download in a dialogbox (or optionally in the notification area). I've come across several good resources on this subject (something like http://progrnotes.blogspot.com/2010/09/c-android.html). Unfortunately, all the examples don't provide a clear indication on how to properly cancel a download per the user's request. So my question is actually quite simple:

Given an asynctask which downloads the file in the background (with httpclient) and displays a dialogbox with download progress and a cancel button, how do I can cancel the download and stop the background task when the button is pressed?

I know killing threads is generally not a good idea, so I will probably need to work with a 'cancel'-variable in my background thread. How do I communicate a stop signal from the button to the asynctask?

Regards,
Ivo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your button call `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` and then check `isCancelled()` from inside `doInBackground(Params... params)`.  In this manner, you can communicate to the background thread that the download should be cancelled, and you can take the appropriate steps to stop it.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like the solution! ( I actually did see the cancel option in the reference, but I read complaints about reliability of this feature ). Checking often on isCancelled() in my thread should work.

Comment: It just called the "OnCancelled" function but the downloader task still running isnt? I want a way to stop the downloading task.. how to do that

Answer (score 3):

I would call [cancel(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) on your AsyncTask object. This will interrupt your thread via [normal interruption handling](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html). You then can ask the AsyncTask if it [isCancelled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled%28%29).

Comment: Putting a `catch (InterruptedException e)` line in the AsyncTask says that `InterruptedException` is never thrown. So this seems not like a working solution.

Comment: What is your reference that "This will interrupt your thread via normal interruption handling"?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to go through this link for the **dark-side of AsyncTasks**: http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.in/2013/04/the-dark-side-of-asynctask.html .

Google has released a library called "Volley" that is used nowadays for faster and better networking .

It solves **Bad points** of AsyncTasks.

[Canceling request using volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)