# cancel GetAsync request from outside of method

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I have large numbers of async requests. At some point, when application is deactivated (paused) I need cancel all requests. I'm looking for a solution to cancel requests outside of async method. can someone point me in a right direction?

Here is chunks of code.

The async method:

```
public async void GetDetailsAsync(string url)
{
    if (this.LastDate == null)
    {
        this.IsDetailsLoaded = "visible";
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsDetailsLoaded");
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        HtmlNode htmlNode = new HtmlNode(0, htmlDocument, 1);
        MovieData Item = new MovieData();
        string HtmlResult;

        try
        {
            HtmlRequest = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            HtmlResult = await HtmlRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        ...
```

calling method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < App.ViewModel.Today.Items.Count; i++)
{
    App.ViewModel.Today.Items[i].GetDetailsAsync(App.ViewModel.Today.Items[i].DetailsUrl);
}
```

deactivate event:

```
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
    //Here i need to stop all requests.
}
```

Comment: `GetAsync` has an overload taking `CancellationToken`

Comment: Well i tried, but still couldn't do it outside of method.

Comment: My best guess is some method which cancels all requests at once.

Comment: What did you  try? Did you declare `CancellationToken` out of methods(as your class's private field?) as it is shared by two methods.

Comment: I declared cancelationTokenSource as public field. (I can't access privet from outside) asd included token at GetAsync method

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancelling file download with httpclient and asynctask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080500/cancelling-file-download-with-httpclient-and-asynctask)

Comment: *All* TPL cancellation questions are duplicate by now. Please search.

Comment: Believe me, I looked at this. I need a mass destruction of all treads at app at same time. :)

Comment: You need to shut down all tasks individually. Search "cancel httpclient".

Comment: httpclient.CancelPendingRequests. I tried this one too. This method cancels requests at current instance. I don't see any way how I can call this from outside of method.

Comment: to usr: this post you mentioned at top of my question is about asynktask for Java-Android.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just [create a single (shared) instance of `CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Then, [tie all asynchronous operations into that token](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2012/12/08/await-httpclient-getstringasync-and-cancellation.aspx):

```
public async void GetDetailsAsync(string url)
{
  ...
  HtmlRequest = await client.GetAsync(uri, _cts.Token);
  ...
}
```

Finally, cancel the CTS at the appropriate time:

```
private void Application_Deactivated(object sender, DeactivatedEventArgs e)
{
  _cts.Cancel();
  _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
}
```

Comment: That worked :) Deactivated method was in different file than async methods so I made a static method CancelAllThreads(); and called it from App.xaml.cs.